# iFrame Sandbox with Content Security Policy

Tags: html, google-chrome, iframe, sandbox, content-security-policy

I assume that this is just a simple misunderstanding of the spec. However, I'm having an issue with including scripts in iFrames protected by sandboxing. Specifically, the code I am dealing with is below.

In top.html:

```
<iframe src="framed.html" sandbox="allow-scripts"></iframe>
```

In framed.html

```
...
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src example.com">
  <script src="http://example.com/script.js"></script>
</head>
...
```

When running this file in Chrome, it gives me the error:

> Refused to load the script 'http://example.com/script.js' because
>   it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "script-src localhost:9000".

Why is it blocking the script from loading? I know that without `allow-same-origin`, the iFrame gets a completely unique origin that is not equal to any other origin. Therefore, `script-src 'self'` wouldn't work. However, I am trying to load the script from an origin explicitly called for in the CSP. Thoughts?

**Update**: Created [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YczLy/) to showcase the issue.

Comment: It's the same with Firefox

Answer (score 12):

When you use a sandboxed page with a unique origin, you can't put a host without scheme in the CSP, that's why the policy is violated. Use `script-src https://example.com` or `script-src http://example.com` or even `script-src https://example.com http://example.com`, and the CSP will correctly be relaxed (note that the CSP is whitelist-based, by default most things are disallowed).

---

As [the grammar from the CSP specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/WD-CSP3-20160913/#framework-directive-source-list) shows, the scheme in a CSP directive is [optional](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5234#section-3.8):

```
; Schemes: "https:" / "custom-scheme:" / "another.custom-scheme:"
scheme-source = scheme-part ":"

; Hosts: "example.com" / "*.example.com" / "https://*.example.com:12/path/to/file.js"
host-source = [ scheme-part "://" ] host-part [ port-part ] [ path-part ]
scheme-part = scheme
              ; scheme is defined in section 3.1 of RFC 3986.
host-part   = "*" / [ "*." ] 1*host-char *( "." 1*host-char )
host-char   = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-"
port-part   = ":" ( 1*DIGIT / "*" )
path-part   = path-abempty
              ; path-abempty is defined in section 3.3 of RFC 3986.
```

But a sandboxed frame without the `allow-same-origin` token will have a `null` origin, and the URL matching algorithm does not allow scheme-less directives to match (relevant parts of the algorithm shown below):

> [6.6.1.6.](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/WD-CSP3-20160913/#match-url-to-source-expression) Does url match expression in origin with redirect count?
>
> Given a URL (*url*), a source expression (*expression*), an origin (*origin*), and a number (*redirect count*), this algorithm returns "`Matches`" if *url* matches *expression*, and "`Does Not Match`" otherwise.
>
> ...
>
> 3. If *expression* matches the `host-source` grammar:
>
>    1. If *url*’s host is `null`, return "`Does Not Match`".
>    2. If *expression* does not have a `scheme-part`, then return "`Does Not Match`" unless one of the following conditions is met:
>
>       1. *origin*’s scheme is *url*’s scheme
>       2. *origin*’s scheme is "`http`", and *url*’s scheme one of "`https`", "`ws`", or "`wss`".
>       3. *origin*’s scheme is "`https`", and *url*’s scheme is "`wss`".

In the given example:

- *origin*'s scheme is `null` (because of the use of `sandbox` without `allow-same-origin`).
- *url* is `http://example.com/script.js`

The `null` origin's scheme does not match any of the last three cases, so the host name without scheme won't match any URL, and therefore the policy is violated.

Comment: Wow - that was incredibly silly of me. Thanks so much for the help. I think I was just going off of examples [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP/CSP_policy_directives) that showed the CSP without the scheme.

Comment: @huntaub On a second thought, I am wrong. The specification **allows** omission of the scheme (because it is within square brackets, which [means that the token is optional](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5234#section-3.8)). It seems more likely that the specification is not correctly adhered to, i.e. a browser bug. Could you unaccept my answer? Then I will delete it.

Comment: Yeah - I can unaccept your answer, although - I wouldn't delete it just yet. It is useful for figuring out _why_ this doesn't work.

Comment: Do you think that I should submit a bug report to Chromium?

Comment: First check whether it is really a bug, and not an oversight from one of us, then create a minimal test case, then post it at http://crbug.com/new.

Comment: @RobW if your answer is incorrect re: scheme, can you edit or remove it?

Comment: @mikemaccana The conclusion was correct, but the explanation was missing. I have corrected the explanation, please take another look.

Comment: Thank you for documenting this, I was pulling my hair out trying when testing on older browsers. It seems that newer chromium (at least v114) has fixed this, OP's jsfiddle loads perfectly without errors.

But indeed, older versions of chrome (maybe < 80, I haven't actually tested) fail for the reason you mentioned. I found https://github.com/w3c/webappsec-csp/issues/166 which I think tries to clarify the matching algorithm for this case?


Possibly related to
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=443444
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=973991